# Python: Missing arguments in string formatting (lazy eval)

Tags: python, string, formatting

i'm trying to do some "post"/"lazy" evaluation of arguments on my strings. Suppose i've this:

```
s = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE {condition}"
```

I'd like to return the string with the `{table_name}` replaced, but not the `{condition}`, so, something like this:

```
s1 = s.format(table_name = "users")
```

So, I can build the hole string later, like:

```
final = s1.format(condition= "user.id = {id}".format(id=2))
```

The result should be, of course:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user.id = 2"
```

I've found this previous answer, this is exactly what I need, but i'd like to use the `format` string function.

[python, format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928526/python-format-string)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Naturally, you're going to escape all the replacement strings to prevent an SQL injection attack - right? ;)

Comment: I hope you're not *ever* letting *any* user input get into this? This sort of code is asking for security holes.

Comment: Of course i won't do it fellas, maybe it wasn't the best example, but was what first came to my mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use the format function because it will raise a KeyError.

`string.Template` supports safe substituion:

```
from string import Template
s = Template('SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE $condition')
s.safe_substitute(table_name='users')

'SELECT * FROM users WHERE $condition'
```

If you use plain variable names (no format specifiers, no indexing, etc..) this will also work (thanks @Simeon Visser for the idea):

```
def myformat(s, *args, **kwargs):
  while True:
    try:
      return s.format(*args, **kwargs)
    except KeyError as e:
      e=e.args[0]
      kwargs[e] = "{%s}" % e

s = "SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE {condition}" 
myformat(s, table_name="users")

'SELECT * FROM users WHERE {condition}'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can replace the condition with itself:

```
s.format(table_name='users', condition='{condition}')
```

which gives us:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE {condition}
```

You can use this string later to fill in the condition.

Comment: replacing something with itself doesnt seem very Pythonic at least from my understanding...

Comment: Well, it's short, clear and it works so that's Pythonic to me :)

Answer (score 1):

This builds on @Karoly Horvath's answer to add support for index keys and attribute access on named keys:

```
import re

def my_format(template, *args, **kwargs):
  next_index = len(args)
  while True:
    try:
      return template.format(*args, **kwargs)
    except KeyError as e:
      key = e.args[0]
      finder = '\{' + key + '.*?\}'
      template = re.sub(finder, '{\g<0>}', template)
    except IndexError as e:
      args = args + ('{' + str(next_index) + '}',)
      next_index += 1
```

So to test it out:

```
class MyObj:
  bar = 'baz'

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<MyObj instance>'

my_obj = MyObj()

template = '{0}, {1}, {foo}, {foo.bar}, {0}, {10}, {missing}'
print my_format(template)
print my_format(template, '1st', '2nd', missing='Not Missing')
print my_format(template, foo=my_obj)
```

Output:

```
{0}, {1}, {foo}, {foo.bar}, {0}, {10}, {missing}
1st, 2nd, {foo}, {foo.bar}, 1st, {10}, Not Missing
{0}, {1}, <MyObj instance>, baz, {0}, {10}, {missing}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this function for some time now, which casts the `Dict` of inputted keyword arguments as a `SafeDict` object that subclasses `Dict`.

```
def safeformat(str, **kwargs):
        class SafeDict(dict):
                def __missing__(self, key):
                    return '{' + key + '}'
        replacements = SafeDict(**kwargs)
        return str.format_map(replacements)
```

I didn't make this up, but I think it's a good solution. The one downside is that you can't call `mystring.safeformat(**kwargs)` - of course, you have to call `safeformat(mystring,**kwargs)`.

---

If you're really interested in being able to call `mystr.safeformat(**kwargs)` (which I am interested in doing!), consider using this:

```
class safestr(str):
    def safeformat(self, **kwargs):
        class SafeDict(dict):
                def __missing__(self, key):
                        return '{' + key + '}'
        replacements = SafeDict(**kwargs)
        return safestr(self.format_map(replacements))
```

You can then create a `safestr` object as `a = safestr(mystr)` (for some `str` called `mystr`), and you can in fact call
`mystr.safeformat(**kwargs)`.

e.g.

```
mysafestr = safestr('Hey, {friendname}. I am {myname}.')
print(mysafestr.safeformat(friendname='Bill'))
```

prints

`Hey, Bill. I am {myname}.`

This is cool in some ways - you can pass around a partially-formatted `safestr`, and could call `safeformat` in different contexts. I especially like to call `mystr.format(**locals())` to format with the appropriate namespace variables; the `safeformat` method is especially useful in this case, because I don't always carefully looks through my namespace.

The main issue with this is that inherited methods from `str` return a `str` object, not a `safestr`. So `mysafestr.lower().safeformat(**kwargs)` fails. Of course you could cast as a `safestr` when using `safeformat`:

`safestr(mysafestr.lower()).safeformat(**kwargs)`,

but that's less than ideal looking. I wish Python just gave the `str` class a `safeformat` method of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight change to @ShawnFumo's answer which has a small bug.  We need to add a word boundary check (the \b in the regular expression) to ensure that we are matching only the failing key and another key that starts with the same string.  This prevents a missing {foo} key from also treating {food} and {foolish} as if they were missing.

```
import re

def my_format(template, *args, **kwargs):
  next_index = len(args)
  while True:
    try:
      return template.format(*args, **kwargs)
    except KeyError as e:
      key = e.args[0]
      finder = r'\{' + key + r'\b.*?\}'
      template = re.sub(finder, r'{\g<0>}', template)
    except IndexError as e:
      args = args + ('{' + str(next_index) + '}',)
      next_index += 1
```

So to test it out:

```
class MyObj:
  bar = 'baz'

  def __repr__(self):
    return '<MyObj instance>'

my_obj = MyObj()

template = '{0}, {1}, {foo}, {foo.bar}, {0}, {10}, {missing}'
print my_format(template)
print my_format(template, '1st', '2nd', missing='Not Missing')
print my_format(template, foo=my_obj)

print

template2 = '{foo} and {food}'
print my_format(template2)
print my_format(template2, food='burger')
print my_format(template2, foo=my_obj, food='burger')
```

Output:

```
{0}, {1}, {foo}, {foo.bar}, {0}, {10}, {missing}
1st, 2nd, {foo}, {foo.bar}, 1st, {10}, Not Missing
{0}, {1}, <MyObj instance>, baz, {0}, {10}, {missing}

{foo} and {food}
{foo} and burger
repr(<MyObj instance>) and burger
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `string.Template.safe_substitute` could be subclassing `string.Formatter` like so:

```
class LazyFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def get_value(self, key, args, kwargs):
        '''Overrides string.Formatter.get_value'''
        if isinstance(key, (int, long)):
            return args[key]
        else:
            return kwargs.get(key, '{{{0}}}'.format(key))

lazyfmt = LazyFormatter()
print lazyfmt.format("{field}: {value}", **{'field': 'foo'})
```

Output:

```
foo: {value}
```