# Type hints for a function that has both named and unnamed kwargs

Tags: python, mypy

My function definition contains both named and unnamed kwargs:

```
def safe_format(text: str, max_errors: int = 10, **kwargs: str) -> None:
    print(text)
    print(max_errors)
    print(kwargs)
```

If I call it without specifying max_errors:

```
safe_format(some_str, **some_dict)
```

I do get the expected result (some_str is printed, then 10, then some_dict). Yet mypy is unhappy and believes I'm trying to use some_dict as a value for max_errors:

```
Argument 2 to "safe_format" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, str]"; expected "int"
```

Is there a specific syntax I can use for mypy to recognize what I'm doing?

Comment: Are you using Python3.8 or later?

Comment: You may use TypedDict if you have a certain set of keys. It resolves your problem

Comment: `safe_format` is intended to be used as a safe version of `.format` (inspired by this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955931/6710525), so the keys cannot be predicted

Comment: So you may have to use typing.overload decorator

Comment: you could make max_errors a keyword only parameter. I would think that would satisfy mypy, but don't have the opportunity to test it right now

Comment: Yes, you'll have to either (1) use `@typing.overload`, making an overload which omits `max_errors` and an overload which accepts it, or (2) bite the bullet and call `safe_format` with an argument even if it's the default value.

Comment: @totooooo re: _"`safe_format` is intended to be used as a safe version of `.format`"_, Are the keys not predictable because the format string is being provided by the user? If so, and if you're using `str.format` under the hood, do note that using [`str.format` with user provided templates can lead to security vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76783239/11082165)

Comment: Thanks. Only admin users can create format strings but it's good to be aware of this vulnerability. I will implement a safer way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I managed to make it work with `typing.overload`

```
from typing import overload


@overload
def safe_format(text: str, max_errors: int = 10, **kwargs: str) -> None:
    ...


@overload
def safe_format(text: str, max_errors=..., **kwargs: str) -> None:
    ...


def safe_format(text: str, max_errors: int = 10, **kwargs: str) -> None:
    print(text)
    print(max_errors)
    print(kwargs)


# mypy doesn't complain
safe_format("FOO", **{"kwarg1": "bar", "kwarg2": "BIGBAR"})
# mypy does complain because of kwarg1
safe_format("FOO", **{"kwarg1": 42, "kwarg2": "BIGBAR"})
```